# Categorias e subcategorias em um único SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de tabelas:

```
CATEGORIAS
id
titulo

SUBCATEGORIAS
id
id_categoria
titulo
```

Queria saber se existe uma forma de trazer todas as categorias e subcategorias de uma vez em um único select em forma de array bidimensional mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
$categorias = array(
   [0] => array(
      ['id'] => 1,
      ['titulo'] => "Categoria 1",
      ['subcategorias'] => array(
         [0] => array(
            ['id'] => 1,
            ['titulo'] => "Subcategoria A"
         ),
         [1] => array(
            ['id'] => 2,
            ['titulo'] => "Subcategoria B"
         ),
         [2] => array(
            ['id'] => 3,
            ['titulo'] => "Subcategoria C"
         )
      )
   ),
   [...] <= E assim por diante...
)
```

Obs: Utilizo PHP com PDO.

Comment: pelo que entendi, basta fazer um `join` das duas tabelas pra trazer tudo num único select

Comment: O problema é que dessa forma ele traz as categorias repetidas.

Comment: sim, o resultado não é multidimensional, você precisa montar a estrutura json... você pode também retornar o resultado das subcategorias como se fosse uma lista, separada por vírgula por exemplo, isso ajuda?

Comment: acho que é impossivel fazer em unico passo eu resolvi isso com recurso dentro do php =/

Comment: para fazer os menus dentro do php eu acabei usando https://github.com/edomaru/codeigniter_multilevel_menu

Comment: @RicardoPontual como seria para separar por vírgula?

Comment: com um unico select vai gerar repetição mesmo afinal o relacionamento é 1 -> n. Então melhor forma seria usar um select e depois trabalhar o resultado no código (no seu caso, com PHP)